# SDL2 Linker Errors with REAL

Tags: sdl-2

No idea what SDL2.lib is trying to find, but it seems to have built incorrectly or something. Even using the files provided on the website for SDL 2.0.3, i can't get my program to link because of the missing symbols.

```
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetBasePath_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetPrefPath_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_NumHaptics_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticName_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticOpen_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticOpened_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticIndex_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_MouseIsHaptic_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticOpenFromMouse_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_JoystickIsHaptic_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticOpenFromJoystick_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticClose_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticNumEffects_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticNumEffectsPlaying_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticQuery_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticNumAxes_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticEffectSupported_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticNewEffect_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticUpdateEffect_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticRunEffect_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticStopEffect_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticDestroyEffect_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticGetEffectStatus_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticSetGain_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticSetAutocenter_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticPause_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticUnpause_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticStopAll_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticRumbleSupported_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticRumbleInit_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticRumblePlay_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_HapticRumbleStop_REAL
1>SDL2.lib(SDL_dynapi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GetPowerInfo_REAL
```

Anyone have any idea why these functions can't be found, or why they even have _REAL at the end of them?

Comment: This is part of SDL dynapi support, you can read more at https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RyanGordon/posts/TB8UfnDYu4U . However, 2.0.3 windows build don't seem to have it; are you completely sure you're linking with the right library? Is there only one SDL2.lib in your lib search path or even FS? What's its md5/sha1? I've just downloaded archive from libsdl.org and it works fine with my old VS2008.